# Reference with environment name context

Tags: cross-referencing, context

I can't figure out how to do somethng like this automatically in ConTeXt:

Example 1 shows that...

Usually, I'd use hyperref package from latex and use `autorefname` after I have defined my prefixes and the format in the preamble. How do I achieve same in ConTeXt? I have seen the tutorials on ConTeXt garden about this but non seem to work for an environment you defined yourself.

```
\setupenumerations[
  before={\blank[medium]},
  after={\blank[medium]},
  alternative=serried,
  right=.,
  distance=0.5em,
  width=fit,
  text=Theorem,
  headstyle=bold,
  titlestyle=bold,
]
\defineenumeration[example][
  text=Example,
  list=all,
  referenceprefix={\sc Example}
]
\starttext

\startexample[reference={ex:zn-ring}]
  ${\mathblackboard Z}_n$ is a ring. 
\stopexample

\in{example}[ex:zn-ring] shows that...

\stoptext
```